# How to perform an action if a value is not in a list?

Tags: jquery

I want to perform an action if a value is not in a list (where the list is the first instance of a particular class).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="links_ul">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test2</li>
</ul>

<input id="my_input">

<button class="click_me">click me</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.click_me', function() {
    var myInputValue = $("#my_input");
    var myInputValueVal = myInputValue.val();
    if($('.links_ul:first li:not(:contains("' + myInputValueVal + '"))')){
        alert(myInputValueVal + " not in list");
    }
});
```

This is alerting both if a value is not in a list and if a value is in the list.

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/fz4AK/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.is(selector)` to check whether the list contains that text or not.

Try,

```
if (! $('.links_ul:first li').is(':contains(' + myInputValueVal + ')'))
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/fz4AK/3/)

Comment: Fails if the text is te, tes, es, t, est.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal Obviously, :contains() will search for the substring. not for the exact word

Comment: I like this answer cause it is the most concise but as mentioned fails on substring.  I tried removing `contains` but then it doesn't work for the full words.  http://jsfiddle.net/fz4AK/7/ Is there a way to use this concise model without failing on substrings?

Comment: @user1063287 so you want to check the exact word right.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes, the exact word.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (! $('.links_ul li').is(':contains(' + myInputValueVal + ')')) {
   alert(myInputValueVal + " not in list");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.click_me', function() {
    var myInputValue = $("#my_input");
    var myInputValueVal = myInputValue.val();

    var $li = $('.links_ul:first li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === myInputValueVal;    
    });    

    if($li.length==0) {
        alert(myInputValueVal + ' not in the list');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fz4AK/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a little bit cleaner and more reusable:

```
function valueExists(selector, value) {

   var exists = false;
   $(selector).each(function () {
       if ($.trim(this.innerHTML) === value) {
           exists = true;
           break;
       }
   });

   return exists;

}

$(document).on("click", ".click_me", function () {

   var value = $("#my_input").value();

   if ( !valueExists(".links_ul > li", value) ) {
       alert("it's not in the list!");
   }

});
```